# Attempt to execute non-instruction in mips assembler?

Tags: mips

```
    .data
stack: .word 3, 2
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la $s1, stack        #assign stack start memory to $s1
    addi $t3, $t3, 0     #clear $t3
    addi $t3, $t3, 4     #assign 4 to $t3
    add $s1, $s1, $t3    #second member of stack
    lw $t1, 0($s1)       #d2  
    addi $t3, $t3, -4    #move $t3 forward
    add $s1, $s1, $t3    #first member of stack
    lw $t0, 0($s1)       #d1
    add $t0, $t0, $t1    #d1 = d1 +d2
    sw $t0, 0($s1)       #store new d1 at d1's location
```

I'm trying to create a mips program, which gets last-1 and last member of the stack, and add them, and store it. I don't care about addi $t3, $t3, 4 or stack: .word 3, 2 it's just for test.

However, when I run this at qtspim I got an error message "attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x0040004c" please enlighten me as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to end your program with a `jr $ra`, otherwise the processor will just keep executing whatever random instructions that happen to come after the `sw $t0, 0($s1)`.